# Java conversion code - why does the division not return the same result?

Tags: java, integer-division

Beginner question.
This might be more of a math problem, I sorted the code out, but I have no idea why the solution works. Please help explain:

As you may know, the formula for coversion from Celsius to Farenheit is

```
  F=C*9/5+32
```

Now, I am trying to write a simple Java code to do that conversion and I've defined the celsius and farenheit as double and also the final variable

```
  final double MAGIC_NUMBER=9/5;
```

then calculated the conversion

```
  farenheit=celsius*MAGIC_NUMBER+32;
```

The result was 24.0 celsius = 56.0 farenheit - which is not correct

I tried then defining the same thing in a different way:

```
  final double MAGIC_NUMBER=1.8;
```

And the result was 24.0 celsius = 75.2 farenheit - which is the correct one. Now, 1.8 is the same thing as 9/5. Why did the second assign work and not the first one?

Here is the whole code:

```
package farenheit;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Farenheit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   //declare variables
   double celsius;
   double farenheit;
   final double MAGIC_NUMBER=1.8;

   //prompt user to give me the temperature in celsius

   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("temperature in celsius= ");
   celsius=in.nextDouble();

   //calculate the conversion

   farenheit=celsius*MAGIC_NUMBER+32;

   //print out the result       
   System.out.printf("%.1f celsius = %.1f farenheit \n", celsius,      farenheit);
}  
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Integer division is different.  9/5 returns 1, not 1.8.  5/9 returns 0, not 0.55555....

Comment: trying changing that to `9.0/5.0` and see if you don't get the result you are expecting.

Comment: @trooper Thanks for the comment, it makes more sense now.